# How to invoke a method upon transition to another route in Ember?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Lets say i have an IndexController like so,

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['PicId'],
PicCreated: function () {
        alert('Pic created');
    }
});
```

And now i have another controller called NewPic

```
App.NewPic = Ember.Controller.extend({
    // the initial value of the `search` property
    model: this.get('model'),
    needs: ["Index"], //says we need the Index controller for this
    actions: {
  var Pic= this.store.createRecord("PicList", obj);
            PicList.save().then(function () {
               this.transitionToRoute('Index');
            });
}
});
```

My question is how do i invoke PicCreated upon transition. I have list of pictures, after the upload i will go back to index page and show a message "Pic created".

Can someone help me,please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transitionToRoute` returns a promise, so you can use the `then` to know when the transition is finished, and call the `PicCreated` method:

```
App.NewPic = Ember.Controller.extend({        
    needs: ["index"],
    actions: {
        createPic: function() {
            var newPicController = this;
            var indexController = this.get('controllers.index');
            // more code here ...

            PicList.save().then(function () {
               newPicController.transitionToRoute('index').then(function() {
                    // show th message
                    indexController.PicCreated();
               });
            });
        }        
    }
});
```